# Laravel 4.2 check array is empty in whereIn clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I make a query with `elequent` i have a problem with `whereIn` clause , if the array is empty it does not return result :

```
$idsUsers = empty(json_decode($data["idsUsers"])) ? null : json_decode($data["idsUsers"]);
$articles = DB::table('articles')
        ->whereIn('user_id',$idsUsers)
        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->paginate(10);
```

How can i use my array in whereIn methode an check if it's not empty or null

Comment: Laravel 4 or 5.2, they have a LOT of diferences making queries.

Comment: Laravel 4.2 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use conditional:

```
$articles = DB::table('articles')->orderBy('created_at','desc');

if (!empty($idsUsers)) {
    $articles = $articles->whereIn('user_id', $idsUsers);
}

$articles = $articles->paginate(10);
```

Comment: this query return collection of stdclass .. can i cast that collection to Article object ?

Comment: Sure. Just replace `DB::table('articles')->` with `Article::`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$idsUsers = empty(json_decode($data["idsUsers"])) ? null : json_decode($data["idsUsers"]);

$articles = DB::table('articles')
              ->where(function($query) use ($idsUsers){
                if(count($idsUsers))
                {
                  $query->whereIn('user_id',$idsUsers);
                }
              })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
```

Hope this will help